# Random characters java

Tags: java, arrays, file, random, character

I have to make a text file in which I'm supposed to put 100 random characters where on each even position should be a small letter and on each odd position should be a capital letter. Also, all the letters are supposed to be separated by a blank field (space). I only succeeded to make a 100 random characters list but I don't know how to do the rest.

```
public class Main {

    public static char getRandomCharacter(char c1, char c2) {
        return (char) (c1 + Math.random() * (c2 - c1 + 1));
    }

    public static char[] createArray() {
        char[] character = new char[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
            character[i] = getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(character[i]);
        }
        return character;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createArray();

    }

}
```

I would appreciate the help.

EDIT: Here's an edited version. However, the output is not much different `b j r m r b k i...`

```
public class Main {

    public static char getRandomCharacter(char c1, char c2) {
        return (char) (c1 + Math.random() * (c2 - c1 + 1));
    }

    public static char[] createArray() {
        char[] character = new char[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
            character[i] = getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(character[i]);
        }
        return character;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] arr = createArray();
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int pos = i + 1;
            if (pos % 2 != 0) {
                String s = "" + arr[i];
                text.append(s.toUpperCase());
            } else {
                text.append(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        String content = text.toString().trim();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it's easier to create a `string` first and then put it into a `txt` file.

You can simply iterate through the random array and check for odd/even positions.
Use `Character.toUpperCase` or `Character.toLowercase` in respective odd even postion and append to the string.

Use `StringBuilder` so that you don't have to create new String objects every time.

```
char[] arr = createArray();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
//iterate thoruh the arr
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int pos = i+1;
    if(pos%2!=0){  // check whether current postion is odd or even                 
        text.append(Character.toUpperCase(arr[i])+" ");// if position is odd then convert it to uppercase
    }else{
        text.append(arr[i]+" ");  // if position is even then convert it toLowercase if needed (if arr contents both upper case and lower case)
    }
}
String content = text.toString().trim(); // trimin to remove any extra space in last or first of the string.
```

To write in file

```
String path = "D:/a.txt";
Files.write( Paths.get(path), content.getBytes());
```

EDIT 1 :
I am not sure why this `Character.toUpperCase` is not working. You can try this below conversion, the drawback is that a `String` object will be created for every even position.

```
String s = ""+ arr[i];
text.append(s.toUpperCase()+" ");
```

EDIT 2: You can use normal `String`

```
String text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int pos = i + 1;
    if (pos % 2 != 0) {
        String s = "" + arr[i];
        text =text + s.toUpperCase()+" ";
    } else {
        text= text + (arr[i] + " ");
    }
}
String content = text.toString().trim();
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Your method did create a space between characters, but the upper case method didn't work for some reason, I'm not sure why. All of the letters are still small on the output.

Comment: I am having `r K o B e P r K r Q o I e W..` as output. I will edit and give a workaround to try

Comment: [Here is a demo](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y5dg5cht)

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work. Maybe I wrote something in the wrong line I'm not sure, I'm new to programming. I edited my post so you can see it, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild I guess. Otherwise, the code should work fine. [demo](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y5dmvw5d)

Answer (score 2):

## Code point

The [Answer by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72417892/642706) looks correct. But, unfortunately, the `char` type is legacy. As a 16-bit value, the `char` type is physically incapable of representing most characters. So I recommend making a habit of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead of `char`.

## `IntSupplier` for `IntStream` of code points

Also, I happened to notice the method [`IntStream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate(java.util.function.IntSupplier)) that takes an [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html). We can write our own implementation of that interface `IntSupplier` that alternates between returning a code point number for an uppercase letter and returning a code point for a lowercase letter.

Within our implementation we define an enum of two objects, to represent uppercase and lowercase.

Our implementation has a constructor taking either of those two enum objects. The passed argument signals the case of the first letter to be generated.

```java
package work.basil.example.rando;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.function.IntSupplier;

public class SupplierOfCodePointForBasicLatinLetterInAlternatingCase
        implements IntSupplier
{
    public enum LetterCase { UPPERCASE, LOWERCASE }

    private LetterCase currentCase;

    public SupplierOfCodePointForBasicLatinLetterInAlternatingCase ( final LetterCase startingCase )
    {
        this.currentCase = startingCase;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAsInt ( )
    {
        int codePoint =
                switch ( this.currentCase )
                        {
                            case UPPERCASE -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 65 , 91 ); // ( inclusive , exclusive )
                            case LOWERCASE -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 97 , 123 );
                        };
        this.currentCase =
                switch ( this.currentCase )
                        {
                            case UPPERCASE -> LetterCase.LOWERCASE;
                            case LOWERCASE -> LetterCase.UPPERCASE;
                        };
        return codePoint;
    }
}
```

When we invoke our customized `IntStream`, we pass a limit of the number of code points to generate.

Finally, we collect all the generate code points into a `StringBuilder` from which we build our final resulting `String` object.

```java
IntStream streamOfCodePoints = IntStream.generate( new SupplierOfCodePointForBasicLatinLetterInAlternatingCase( SupplierOfCodePointForBasicLatinLetterInAlternatingCase.LetterCase.UPPERCASE ) );
String result =
        streamOfCodePoints
                .limit( 100 )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```

> ZtAxIqWfEhOeHdSgOpMyPuJwLuSwJqHzUwSlLeQnFoFcAaMfOxMiBnVuZxOpCvPuLiZhBmIrGaBqZzIyOoUhAdFmXgArVwWqBoWr

### Adding SPACE

Your requirements specify that each generated letter be separated by a space.

Somewhere define a constant for the code point of 32 for the SPACE character.

```
private static final int SPACE = 32; // ASCII & Unicode code point for SPACE character is 32 decimal.
```

Then alter our `.collect` line to use expanded syntax. Instead of a method reference, we use a lambda. In that lambda, we call `StringBuilder#appendCodePoint` twice. In the first call we append the generate code point. In the second call we append the SPACE character’s code point.

To eliminate the SPACE at the very end, we trim.

```java
IntStream streamOfCodePoints = IntStream.generate( new SupplierOfCodePointForBasicLatinLetterInAlternatingCase( SupplierOfCodePointForBasicLatinLetterInAlternatingCase.LetterCase.UPPERCASE ) );
String result =
        streamOfCodePoints
                .limit( 100 )
                .collect(
                        StringBuilder :: new ,
                        ( stringBuilder , codePoint ) -> stringBuilder.appendCodePoint( codePoint ).appendCodePoint( App.SPACE ) ,
                        StringBuilder :: append
                )
                .toString()
                .trim() ;
```

> X t D j J g J m Y c J a E e H m U c H b U a R t J g R n G r V s P e B z D k G f H e Z r W t U l U f C z R j F z G k Z f A y I z N i L g Q y Q w D w D w P s F y E n J n I i R b B u H x U m B g K w C k

If you want to keep the SPACE on the end, drop the call to [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()).

Comment: The OP wanted them separated by a space.

Comment: @WJS You are correct. I had missed that point. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already sent the project, but this was pretty helpful. I'm sure it'll be of great use for my future tasks.

Comment: Why do you say my answer looks correct?  It's correct since I caveated it as an ASCII solution. which `char` supports just fine.   And the Character class makes extensive use of `char` and `char[]` even when processing code points.  It would seem to me that quite a few of those methods should be deprecated if one is not supposed to use char types.

Comment: @WJS By “looks”, I did not mean “falsely appears”. I meant “I looked briefly, and upon first inspection all seems in order though I’ve not done a thorough evaluation”. As for `char` not being deprecated, many parts of Java have yet to receive their deserved deprecation. Ex: the legacy date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar` supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Java could really use a grand revamp of its text handling, a *Project Papyrus* I would call it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using Streams of ASCII characters.  In the ASCII table, `a-z` are adjacent as are `A-Z`.  So for any value `d` from `0 to 25`, `(char)(d + 'a')` will be a lower case letter and (char)(d + 'A') will be an upper case letter.

- create a `Random` instance.
- stream the integers from `0 to 100` for `100` characters.
- check the parity of `i` and add either 'a' or 'A' to the value `d`
- map to a String and join using a space as a delimiter.

```
Random r = new Random();
String str = IntStream.range(0,100).mapToObj(
        i -> {
            int d = r.nextInt(26);
            return String.valueOf((char)(i % 2 == 0 ? d + 'a' : d +  'A'));
        }).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

System.out.println(str);
```

prints something similar to

```
j H o C y X h H k A y F z J b D x A z R t Y w O d A a F q F t R n A i B k Y g F 
y X c O r I h E k K t R n L a S d C s T m S z Y z H a V y N o R t S y I t E l W 
q X l E v S h D r C y N h O o C l D u X
```

To write to a file, use `try with resources` and also catch IO errors.

```
String file = "f:/myOutputFile.txt";
try (FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File(file))) {
    output.write(str);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is how you could do it with a simple loop.

- initialize a `StringBuilder` to the a lower case letter for the 0th location which is even.  This also allows prepending the space to avoid a trailing space at the end.
- Then iterate from `1 to 100` to get the other `99` characters.
- first append the space, then append the appropriate character as was done in the previous example.
- Then you can write the `StringBuilder` as a string as shown above.

```
StringBuilder sb =
        new StringBuilder().append((char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    int d = r.nextInt(26);
    sb.append(" ")
            .append((char) (i % 2 == 0 ? d + 'a' : d + 'A'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I already did the task in Mr. Sayan's way and sent the project, but I'm sure this will definitely help me out in the future, for my future tasks.

Comment: Glad I could provide assistance.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  And if you haven't done so, I recommend taking the [tour].  And your question was fine and conformed to guidelines but you still may want to check out [ask] to avoid potential problems in the future.